# How to setup a backbone/marionette app for ADFS authentication?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I have an app that needs to authenticate with ADFS. Currently when my backbone model requests the URL the app server returns the ADFS 302 redirect and the process stops there since jquery will not process the redirect.

I have an alternative method where the app goes to an authentication page and I load a fake request to the server in an iframe, this handles all redirects, the ADFS authentication form and the fedAuth cookies, then I go to my app as usual and the server requests go through ok.

This solution however does not account for the authentication token expiration, which can happen at any time.

Has anyone figured out how to do the ADFS negotiation when the backbone model sends a request to the server?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but with oauth instead of adfs.  The secret is to override Backbone.ajax... In there, call the service but check the response for 302 before returning.  If it's 302, do your auth stuff and then retry the original request and return •that• result.  Now your models/collections can call services all day long without having any awareness of the auth problems being handled behind the scenes on each request.

Comment: Yeah this seems the way to go.  I am doing something similar not in backbone, but as an $.ajaxPrefilter. Do you recall how you chained the response from the second call to the original call? I am pretty close, but my first call comes back before the second call after the authentication is complete.